# Text Overlap on Image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image which I want to overlap a piece of text at the bottom with a transparent black background.

Whats the easiest way to achieve this ,

```
<img src="http://assets3.parliament.uk/iv/main-large//ImageVault/Images/id_7382/scope_0/ImageVaultHandler.aspx.jpg" alt=""> 
<div>  
    <p class="description_content">example</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap the `img` and the `p` tag in that `div`, then apply `position` attribute and style as you want. One minute and I give you a basic example for you to work with.

Comment: Why was this voted down? @felix001 has provided code demonstrating she's tried to solve this issue and it's a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Wrap the `img` and the `p` tag in that `div`, then apply `position` property and style as you want.*

Something like this for example...

### HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://assets3.parliament.uk/iv/main-large//ImageVault/Images/id_7382/scope_0/ImageVaultHandler.aspx.jpg" alt="" />
    <p class="description_content">example</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 460px;
    height: 230px;
}
img, p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
p {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}
```

### RESULT

[image: Basic example]

***jsfiddle example:*** <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/n8k326g6/</kbd>

---

***This is just an example so you can make an idea on how can be done. <sup>(just one way)</sup>***

---

**EDIT:** *Added `responsive` example*

For a `responsive` solution, remove the `width` & `height` from that `div` and give the `position:absolute`propertie *only* to the `p` tag.

### CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
img, p {
    width: 100%;
}
p {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}
```

### RESULT

[image: Basic responsive example]

***updated jsfiddle example:*** <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/n8k326g6/1/</kbd>

---

***Again, is just an example to point you in the right direction...***

---

Comment: Thanks but can this not be done without setting the width and height in the div styling. As I need it to resize accrongly to my page.

Comment: Yes, of course you can, I just give you a reference to understand the logic of one of the ways to get what you want.

Comment: If i remove the height width the overlap dissapears ?

Comment: Does not disappear, It's going up because when having all objects with `position: absolute` in the content, without a defined height in the container (or any content at all), the container doesn't have any height to adapt. ***Any way, that's not what you ask... please edit your question to be more specific***, and remember that we will try to help you understand the concept and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Nevermind.. remove the `position:absolute` from `img` tag and you will have better approachment of what you're looking for... (I think) See Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8k326g6/1/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do is by putting the elements in a div and giving it position relative and each of the elements an position absolute.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
     <img src="http://assets3.parliament.uk/iv/mainlarge//ImageVault/Images/id_7382/scope_0/ImageVaultHandler.aspx.jpg">
     <div class="title">Example</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    position: relative;
}

.content .title {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   background: blue;
   padding: 10px 10px;
   color: #fff;
  }
```

I've made an example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/y7j42q1s/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything inside a div:

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="http://assets3.parliament.uk/iv/main-large//ImageVault/Images/id_7382/scope_0/ImageVaultHandler.aspx.jpg" alt=""> 
    <div>  
        <p class="description_content">example</p>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Set these styles:

```
.imageContainer{
    position: relative;
}
.imageContainer div{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    backgorund-color: black;
}
.imageContainer div p{
    color: white;
}
```

Then make the background of that inner div transparent. I'd suggest making a 1px by 1px transparent png file, and make that the background image of the div.

Comment: the black background does fit over the image correctly.

Comment: Then all you need to do is drop that background color, and replace it with a transparent png background image, and you'll be set. That, or you could set an opacity style on the entire div, but that would make the text semi-transparent as well.

Comment: i tried this but it failed to work. If I change background to background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); the caption goes far larger l

Comment: If the image will always be a set width, then just make the div container the necessary width. The div with the black background will take a 100% width unless otherwise specified.